# When can we use Weiterstrass M-test and when not?

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ consider the series
$$
S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}
$$
Then I have to show that $S$ converges uniformly. I have been told before in here that we are not able to use Weiterstrass M-test when the convergent series we find depend on $x$. But how does this change, for example, if we let $x \in [-K,K]$ where $0< K < \infty$? I am studying for my Analysis exam and I have some answers for questions like this where the professor has provided the following answer:

Let $x \in [-K,K]$ where $0 < K < \infty$. Then we have
$$
\left| \frac{2x}{x^2+n^2} \right| \leq \frac{2|x|}{n^2} \leq \frac{2K}{n^2}
$$
where $\sum_{n=1} \frac{2K}{n^2}$ is well-known convergent. It follows from Weiterstrass M-test that $S$ converges uniformly on $[-K,K]$ where $0 < K < \infty$.

But I simply don't see how this differ from if we just let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and get that

$$
\left| \frac{2x}{x^2+n^2} \right| \leq \frac{2|x|}{n^2} 
$$
Why doesn't Weiterstrass M-test work in this instance? It is because $\mathbb{R}$ is not a compact set?

Comment: You need  $2|x|/n^2 <M_n$ for All! $x$, reals, in your case. For any $M_n$, real, choose $x$ large enough (fixed n) and you'll have $M_n < 2|x|/n^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Peter.

Comment: Mathias. Ok now?

Comment: Yes I think so :)

Comment: Reference, perhaps read again the statement:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To conclude from M-test that $\sum f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent you have to produce  sequence of positive  **constants**  $c_n$ such that $\sum c_n <\infty$ and $|f_n(x)| \leq c_n$ for all $n$ and all $x$. In the present case $\frac {2 |x|} {n^{2}}$ does not have a bound of this type because there is no bound for $|x|$. Hence the bound  $\frac {2 |x|} {n^{2}}$ does not yield the conclusion.

EDIT: For uniform convergence on $[-K,K]$ your inequality is good enough.

Comment: But if $x \in [-K,K]$ where $0 < K < \infty$ we get the desired bound on $\frac{2K}{n^2}$?

Comment: Yes.  You get uniform convergence on $[-K,K]$ for all $K$.  But that does not imply uniform convergence on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks. I am also only asked to prove uniform convergence on $[-K,K]$. I probably should have wrote that.